# How to use a inner join in Fluent NHibernate to fetch a single property from the right table

Tags: nhibernate, .net-core, fluent-nhibernate

I have a query that fetches every property from one table, however the query should fetch **one** additional property from another table.

*I'm using a simple example where querying every property from the second table wouldn't have any affect in performance, however the real situation does have many properties.*

This is the queried table model:

```
public class Car
{
    public long Id;
    public long SellerId;
    public string Name;
    public string SellerName;
}
```

However, in the SellerName property is not being mapped, since this property is in another model:

```
public class Seller
{
    public long Id;
    public string SellerName;
}
```

The Car class mapping is currently as follow:

```
Property(x => x.Id);
Property(x => x.SellerId);
Property(x => x.Name);
```

This will create a model like this one:

```
Car Table
|------------------------------------------------|
|Id         | SellerId      | Name              |
|1          | 1             | Car Number one    |
|------------------------------------------------|

Employee Table
|---------------------------|
|Id         | Name          |
|1          | John Doe      |
|---------------------------|
```

Using a simple query I can easily use an inner join to gather the Car data with the related employee name:

```
select c.*, p.Name from Car c
inner join Employee e on c.Id = e.EmployeeId
```

I've already tried this query:

```
var query = from car in session.Query<Car>() 
    join employee in session.Query<Employee>() on car.SellerId equals employee.Id
    select new Car
    {
        Id = car.Id,
        SellerId = car.SellerId,
        Name = car.Name,
        ClientName = employee.ClientName
    };
```

But this actually creates two queries in the database, one for the Client table and another one for the Employee one. And this isn't using Linq, which is also a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First point here is, you have to use `virtual` properties for NHibernate's behaviour. You could map the relation on your model, for sample

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }    
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual long SellerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Seller { get; set; }
}
```

And your map,

```
public class CarMap : ClassMap<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
        // map other properties...

        // You could map the the SellerId to be easy to access here (just readonly, use the reference to persist)
        Map(x => x.SellerId).Column("SellerId").Not.Nullable().ReadOnly();

        References(x => x.Seller).Column("SellerId");
    }
}
```

Given you have a right mapped model and you are using `Linq`, you could use `Fetch` method from `NHibernate.Linq` namespace and it will force a join for you avoiding the lazy loading. For sample:

```
var data = session.Query<Car>()
                  .Fetch(x => x.Seller)
                  .ToList();
```